# JS only execute if statement based on condition

Tags: javascript

I am fetching data from an api and I need to render a component based on an if statement and I cant seem to figure it out. A customer has an array of roles. Customer.items is an array of customer objects. This is the if statement I am trying but doesnt work:

```
{customers?.items?.length > 1 && !roles.includes("Super") && (...component
```

Basically I need to check if roles array has "Super" and `customers.items` only has one element then dont render the component.

Also if roles is "Super" and customer.items.length > 1 then still render the component

```
customers.items: [{id: 2, name: "G"}, {id: 3, name: "H"}]
roles: ["Super", "Admin"]
```

Comment: Please give  a sample snippet of your customers object and roles array

Comment: I added an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will render the component in all cases except when `customers.items` has only one element and if the roles include `'Super'`.

```js
const hasSingleCustomer = customers?.items?.length === 1
const hasSuperRole = roles.includes('Super'))


{!(hasSingleCustomer && hasSuperRole) && <Component />}
```

You can also write it as `{(!hasSingleCustomer || !hasSuperRole) && <Component />}` if you prefer.

Comment: Maybe I worded it weirdly but the only condition when the component should NOT render is when the role is super and customer.items.length === 1

Comment: If role is "Admin" it doesnt matter what the length is, still render component

Comment: @ousmane784 Ah, got it. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, If role is "Admin" and customer.items.length === 0 the component should still render

Comment: @ousmane784, please list down all conditions in your question

Comment: @ousmane784 Just updated my answer to reflect the logic you explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach

```js
{(customers.items.length > 1 && roles.includes("Super")) ? <If Success Component/> : <Failure Component>}
```

I have written as per your request, as I am checking if the roles array has "Super" in it, You can still manipulate the operation inside the brackets(), and we have to use ? and : to make sure the conditions work,

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to split the equation/ conditions into smaller variables and then use them to create a validity condition. This way, your code is more readable and easier to maintain

```js
const length = customers.items.length
const isSuperUser = roles.includes('Super')
const isAdminUser = roles.includes('Admin')
const isAllowedForSuper = isSuperUser && length === 1
const isAllowedForAdmin = isAdminUser && length === 0

if (isAllowedForSuper || isAllowedForAdmin) {
  return <Component {...props} />
}
return null
```